# How do I wire up a TextBox to dynamically run a search in my ASP.NET page using jQuery or AJAX, just like Google's "Instant Predictions"?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search

I've looked around quite a bit and have been able to put together some clues from various sources. But I've not been able to find a resource that'll help me wire up everything from beginning to end. I want my page to do exactly what Google does with its Instant Predictions; As the user types, a list shows up below the TextBox dynamically with each keystroke.

I'm assuming this uses some combination of AJAX & jQuery.

Also, this is standard WebForms, not MVC.

Comment: How about that http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since Amiram answered via comment, I guess I'll answer my own question here with his answer.

The answer is the AutoCompleteExtender via the AjaxControlToolkit. Thanx Amiram!!!